# Z motors work synchronously ToyRep

Tags: ramps-1.4, reprap, z-axis

I have a problem with Z direction. As you know it has two motors. And my problem is that one sometimes goes to the different direction (so basically one is screwing and another one unscrewing). It is like random, sometimes it is ok, sometimes this one goes to the different direction. Could you help me, please? Wiring is like in building tutorial. The tutorial is here http://reprap.org/wiki/ToyREP_Build_Manual . I am using Marlin and Pronterface. Code I took here http://reprap.org/wiki/ToyREP_User_Manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the wiring of the motor. According to different sources it says to check wiring, everything seemed ok, but I've found one wire was damaged.

Comment: Totally. And it's worth checking from time to time as weak soldering may appear a bit later.